# IndexError: list index out of range in array search

Tags: python, search, linear-search

I'm making a simple program in Python to perform a linear search. But when I run this program it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raj\Documents\EclipseProject\PythonProject1\myProgram.py", line 25, in <module>
    if array[myNumber] == search:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my program:

```
array = []

numCase = input("Enter your number cases: ")

numCase = int(numCase)
array = [numCase]

print("Enter the number with", numCase, "times.")

for i in range(0, numCase):
    myNumber = input()
    myNumber = int(myNumber)
    array = [myNumber]

print("Enter the values which you're looking for: ")
search = input()
search = int(search)

for c in range(0, numCase):
    if array[myNumber] == search:
        print(search, "is present at", (c+1))
        break

# If number is absent!!
if c == numCase:
    print(search, "is not present!!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current  issue is this line

```
array = [myNumber]
```

All that you are doing is setting `array` to be a list of 1 element repeatedly with this line, as opposed to adding each element to `array`. Use the increment operator `+=` instead, so that you are actually adding each element to `array`:

```
array += [myNumber]
```

As a much more idiomatic alternative, it looks as though you are prompting the user to input the same number 'x' times. As mentioned by [TheBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604159/theblackcat) you could simply build `array` with

```
array = list(range(numCase))
```

if this is in fact what you are attempting to do.

Additionally, you should be using `c` as your array index as it is what you are iterating over.

Comment: Although it would be easier to just do `array = list(range(numCase))`